# Paperclip reports that an uploaded image is missing. How can I make it find it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Paperclip is able to successfully upload an image (it is uploaded to the appropriate folder on the server). However, when I try to view the image, it reports it as missing.

models/photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :image
attr_accessor :image_file_name, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at
has_attached_file :image, styles: {small: "300x300>" },
url  "/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
path: ":rails_root/public/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 


validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_size :image, less_than: 5.megabytes
end
```

Viewing the image: (photos/show.html.erb):

```
<% if @photo.image? %>
    <%= image_tag @photo.image.url(:small) %>
<% else %>
    Missing image <%= @photo.id %>
<% end %>
```

This outputs "Missing image" with the correct photo id.

Despite this, uploaded photos are stored at the correct path, and are accessible via the correct url, e.g.

```
 http://localhost:3000/photos/1/small/1351546785_accepted_48.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue was that image_file_name was stored as nil in the database.

attr_accessor :image_file_name was blocking image_file_name from having an appropriate value so it had to be removed. I had added this line because of an error that made it seem that it was required. To get rid of the error, the database migration had to be updated with:

```
def change
  create_table :photos do |t|
    t.string :image_file_name
    t.string :image_content_type
    t.integer :image_file_size
    t.datetime :image_updated_at

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was this:

**By default** your generated controller that you want to add the :photo attribute to defines "create" like this:

```
def create
    @setting = Setting.new(setting_params)
end
```

**Just cange it to:**

```
def create
    @setting = Setting.create(params[:setting])
end
```

(Just to be clear; Change setting to your own scaffold name.)